# How can I manipulate incoming Analytics data on Google BigQuery before reading it on DataStudio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, looker-studio

I'm new to the Google infrastructure. I have Google Analytics and Firebase Analytics linked to BigQuery. I need to perform some manipulations on the data, to then read the transformed data from DataStudio to generate a dashboard.

I can't figure out the "best" / industry-standard way to perform this type of operation.

This is the idea I came up with:

- Setup a table partition with a daily granularity, based on insertion date
- Do one of the following things:

1. Setup a scheduled query that runs every 24 hours, reads the data from the new partitions, transforms it, copies it in the table with the formatted data
2. Setup an Apps Script or a Cloud Function to be triggered either daily or based on the event of the creation of a new partition (whatever of the 2 is possible) to process the data
3. Setup DataFlow to process the data (either before putting the data on BigQuery, or after)

I don't know how to do any of these things yet, and whether any of these is the correct option or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datastudio allows you to display data, not to manipulate them. One exception, in the datasource you can define a custom SQL query, and like that you can perform transformation in the query before displaying the data.

That being said, you have to prepare your data before displaying it. The ELT pattern is very popular with BigQuery, it means: run a query in BigQuery to transform the data and store them in BigQuery again.

So, you have to run a query. Use a scheduled query, a Cloud Functions + scheduler, a Cloud Workflow + scheduler, or whatever you want, it doesn't matter (I have a preference for Workflow).

To be efficient (speed and cost) don't use dataflow when the data are already in BigQuery and you have to sink them in BigQuery also.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I know that I have to ingest pre-processed data in DataStudio. I wanted to understand more detailed info about how to implement ELT with BigQuery. 
Anyway, you gave me some useful tips of things to look into, thank you.